# Setting up a CNAME / Nickname for a remote server

Tags: ssh, dns, digital-ocean

Let's say I have a digital ocean droplet - `68.456.72.184`

When `ssh`-ing into my remote server, I'd rather not have to type out the whole `ssh` command -

```
ssh 68.456.72.184
```

The host's name is `Stormtrooper` - how do I make it so that client machines can ssh into the server via

```
ssh Stormtrooper
```

I imagine this requires some sort of configuration on the local client machine that's connecting? In what order does does a client machine search for host names? I imagine there's some local setting where it looks for "Stormtrooper"'s IP address, and if not found it it looks in the local network, and then looks in the "global" network (i.e. public DNS).

I'm not quite sure how that lookup process works, so an explanation there would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create local `ssh_config` in `~/.ssh/config` with a content:

```
Host Stormtrooper
  Hostname 68.456.72.184
```

And then you can ssh to that server using `ssh Stormtrooper` (even tab completion will work for you).

Connecting using FQDN will work too if you have correctly set up DNS. If you have a domain `Stormtrooper.tld` pointing to this IP, you are able to `ssh` using

```
ssh Stormtrooper.tld
```

For local network resolving, you would need local DNS, which would do this translation for you.

Comment: Thanks! I imagine that companies do something similar when setting up an internal network with a VPN - create DNS records that resolve within an internal network? Also I learned since asking this question you can also name hosts in `/etc/hosts` locally, which I guess is a basic version of DNS.